# Creating datapoints on mouseclick Chart.js

Tags: javascript, dataset, chart.js, points, mouseclick-event

I am new to Chart.js and JavaScript. Currently working with a line chart, and now I want to add custom data points to a mouse click event (when I press somewhere on the data set, it takes the current value of the Y axis and using that value it creates a data point in that place). I took the code from http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html and trying to modify it. Here is a link to my current chart:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9MF1.jpg

I am using the basic chart.bundle.js library, and used D3.js libraries for making data points draggable.

Trying to implement the creation of points per mouse click using the following code, but it seems that it's not good so far.

```
document.getElementById('canvas').onclick = function(e){
    //getting value by pressing on dataset 
     value = chartInstance.scales[scale].getValueForPixel(e.clientY)
     //trying to create dataPoint 
     myLineChart.points.push(new this.PointClass({
                    y: value;
                    strokeColor: this.datasets[datasetIndex].pointStrokeColor,
                    fillColor: this.datasets[datasetIndex].pointColor
                    }));
    //after all updating my chart
    chartInstance.Update(0)
};
```

Maybe anyone could explain more about this library and how it creates data points?

Comment: What exactly does not work yet?

Comment: I guess something with point class, bad call or smth like that. I don't know how to create that datapoint, so i found that example with PointClass but i believe it doesn't suit in my context. So i need another possible solution, chart.js datapoint constructor or idk...

Answer (score 0):

Every new point in the chart is data, so you need to add that point in the data (chartData.data.dataset[]) array. Instead of adding to the, myLineChart.points which i'm not sure why you have used you should add the data-point in the data array and the UI decorations such as colors are supposed to be specified in the chartOptions.scales.yAxes[] array. Therefore in order to add the point in the chart use:

```
// here i is the corresponding parameter for which you want to add the new point
chartInstance.data.datasets[i].push(value); 
chartInstance.update();
```